# setTabSFromPagerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

right now i m using latest version of appcompat and design support library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

now i m facing some deprecation

```
 private void setupTabLayout() {
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter); <!-- deprecated -->
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
}
```

anyone know what i have to use instead.. help me.. thank you

Comment: `setupWithViewPager` call is enough. There is no need to use both.

Comment: Dude just hover your mouse over the warning and it'll literally tell you how to fix the problem. Worst case scenario - google the "deprecated" thing and find an answer in 4.5 seconds.

Comment: its only says your method is deprecated.. thats all.. and say put inspection for that method.. and this is not the solution.. you know that right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from TabLayout documentation on `setTabsFromPagerAdapter` :

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)} to link a TabLayout with a ViewPager
 * together. When that method is used, the TabLayout will be automatically updated
 * when the {@link PagerAdapter} is changed.
 */
@Deprecated
public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(@Nullable final PagerAdapter adapter) {
    setPagerAdapter(adapter, false);
}
```

So just like Nikola Despotoski said in comment, calling `setupWithViewPager` is enough.